# android:allowBackup="true" doesn't work android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

After uninstall the app and install it again, shared preference data doesn't save.
My code is: at Application tag

```
 android:allowBackup="true"
 android:allowClearUserData="false"
 android:fullBackupOnly="true"
```

Also I tried to use backupAgent and backup rules xml
but all these trials have no result.

Comment: `allowBackup` is supposed to prevent or allow any Backup utility to save your user data or shared preferences. It doesn't work during uninstall/install unless you actually use a backup app or `adb backup`

Comment: I have got it working for same device but not on second device. If you want this on same device then you can check my code in description https://stackoverflow.com/q/69400776/782299

Answer (score 0):

Whether to allow the application to participate in the backup and restore infrastructure. If this attribute is set to false, no backup or restore of the application will ever be performed, even by a full-system backup that would otherwise cause all application data to be saved via adb. The default value of this attribute is true.

Note: If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher, you cannot disable device-to-device migration of your app's files. The system automatically allows this functionality.

You can still disable cloud-based backup and restore of your app's files by setting this attribute to false, even if your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher.